# Python: Concatenate URL and Integer

Tags: python, string, url, urllib2, string-concatenation

I am trying to concatenate url and integer base on the iteration of the loop. But I am getting error: `TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting`

```
for i in range(0,20):
    convertedI = str(i)
    address = 'http://www.google.com/search?q=%s&num=100&hl=en&start='.join(convertedI) % (urllib.quote_plus(query))
```

I also tried to urllib.urlencode function but ended up getting the same error.

I guess I should have mentioned in addition to query which is a string that I pass it in in my main I want assign current iteration value to the start parameter in the url > `&start=1`

so first iteration I would like to have my url as

```
http://www.google.com/search?q=%s&num=100&hl=en&start=1' % (urllib.quote_plus(query))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for i in range(0, 20):
    address = 'http://www.google.com/search?q=%s&num=100&hl=en&start=%s' % (urllib.quote_plus(query), i)
```

No need to use `str` as `%s` implicitly does that for you.  Nor is there a need to `join`, as `join` is used to take multiple strings within a sequence and pull them together with a join character.  You just want simple string formatting.

Comment: This doesn't use `i` anywhere in the URL, which the question clearly intended to.

Comment: @DavidRobinson yup, the original construction confused me, I assume he means to concatenate `i` to the end so I've updated my answer

Comment: I have edited the question to be more clear. Sorry for any confusion.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are misunderstanding what `join` does.  It uses its argument as a delimiter to join the elements of a passed sequence:

```
>>> ','.join(['a', 'b', 'c'])
'a,b,c'
```

It sounds like you just want to do `"http://..." + convertedI`, but it's not clear exactly what you're trying to do.  Where do you want `convertedI` and the `urllib.quote_plus(query)` value to go in the string?

Comment: I tried this but I am getting TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting 
address = 'http://www.google.com/search?q=%s&num=100&hl=en&start=' + convertedI % (urllib.quote_plus(query))

Comment: Why did you put a semicolon in there? As you have it, you'd have to put parentheses around the url and `convertedl` (order of operations would otherwise try and add the query to the `convertedl` string). Daniel DiPaulo's answer is best, though.